# How to deal with np.array as training set in Image Generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing a ML model that takes pixel values from a numpy array as training and testing data. I defined a function that divides the dataset into images and labels. My task is to use Image Generator for data augmentation and then train the model. Everything goes smoothly until I am to train the model. It keeps giving me errors about the loss function used. When I use categorical_crossentropy it says I can either use 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' or use function to_categorical. Well I tried both and there were still errors so I decided to try and use tf.convert_to_tensor() on my labels but now I get a shape error:

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (126, 25, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

This is my code:

```
training_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(training_labels)
testing_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(testing_labels)


# Create an ImageDataGenerator and do Image Augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale = 1./255,
            rotation_range=40,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            fill_mode='nearest'
        )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(training_images, 
            training_labels,
            batch_size=126
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(
                testing_images, 
                testing_labels,
                batch_size=126
)


# Keep These
print(training_images.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
    
# Their output should be:
# (27455, 28, 28, 1)
# (7172, 28, 28, 1)
```

And here goes the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile Model. 
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the Model
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=2)


model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels, verbose=0)
```

***I got stuck with it, I googled for solution but with no success. Can you please help me somehow make a move?***

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When using categorical cross entropy as the loss function, the labels should be one hot encoded and hence the number of neurons present in the final layer should be equal to the number of classes present in the dataset and that's the error you are getting. Since the number of output neurons is 3, I'm guessing you have 3 classes and hence the shape of training_labels/testing_labels should be (num of images in train/test, 3).

Below is a small snippet for cifar dataset.

```
from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

num_classes = 10 

# convert to one hot encoding 
# shape will be (60000, 10) since there are 60000 images and 10 classes in cifar
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
# shape will be (10000, 10) since there are 10000 images and 10 classes in cifar
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32), epochs=2)
```